# Accessing another private GitHub repository in Docker image build & GitHub Action context

Tags: docker, pip, github-actions

I'm trying to build my Docker image with GitHub action using the official docker/build-push-action action. The action provides secret GIT_AUTH_TOKEN for the build by default but I seem not to be able to use the token to read another private repository from the same organization (install pip package). The same Dockerfile builds fine locally when I provide a working token for the build.

Am I supposed to be able to use the default GIT_AUTH_TOKEN or do I need to retrieve a token from Secrets Manager as we do on Jenkins that I'm trying to get rid of. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate a different PAT to clone the other repo. Bring that token in as a secret and use it in your workflow to checkout

Answer (score 0):

I also must conclude after further testing and research that the github provided workflow token gives privileges to the current repository only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).